# Listar pastas/subPastas e arquvios existentes em uma específica pasta raíz

Tags: c#, asp.net

É possível via código listar as pastas/arquivos existentes em uma pasta específica ?

Exemplo
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E jogar essa lista em uma grid/table na WEB para o usuário saber se a pasta que ele quer criar já existe?

Comment: Sim, é possível, mas não é o mais recomendado. Você pode simplesmente tentar criar a pasta, capturar o erro caso ela já exista e passar esse retorno ao usuário. Outra prática comum é você utilizar guids para criar as pastas e guardar no banco o seu apelido. Assim todos os usuários poderiam ter a sua pasta chamada "Teste".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim, é possível, mas não é o mais recomendado. Você pode simplesmente testar se já existe e passar esse retorno ao usuário.

Outra prática comum é você utilizar guids para criar as pastas e guardar no banco o seu apelido. Assim todos os usuários poderiam ter a sua pasta chamada "Teste".

Para listar você pode partir desse código:

```
string caminho = @"C:\Raiz\";
foreach (string item in Directory.GetDirectories(caminho))
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Remove(0, caminho.Length));
}
```

Para verificar se o diretório não existe você deve consultar antes, porque o método `Directory.CreateDirectory()` só vai falhar caso o caminho seja inválido ou exista alguma restrição de segurança. Se ele já existe ele apenas ignora a instrução.

```
string raiz = @"C:\Raiz\";
string novoDir = "IR";
string mensagem = string.Empty;


if (!Directory.Exists(raiz + novoDir))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(raiz + novoDir);
    mensagem = string.Format("O diretório \"{0}\" foi criado com sucesso!", novoDir);
}
else
{
    mensagem = string.Format("O diretório \"{0}\" já existe, escolha um novo nome!", novoDir);
}

Console.WriteLine(mensagem);
```

Comment: Na verdade a idéia seria não armazenar no banco e sim já armazenar os uploados/criação de novas pastas direto no diretório fisico!

Comment: E na hora de consultar, como você vai saber o que pertence a cada usuário?

Comment: Não haverá esse tipo de validação, a pasta raíz será um lugar para apenas disponibilizar tutorias para todos os usuários

Comment: Ok, ficou mais alguma dúvida?